Issue with connecting to my AT&T router through the browser
I tried to connect to my router using http://192.168.1.254 which is the ip address of my router. I also tried https and putting the port number of :8000 after the URL. No luck with either of these methods.
I was able to connect when I connected to the router via an ethernet cable but I want to be able to connect without that.

it's possible that the router does not allow management through WiFi ... I had one like that

@John yes it was isolation only issue (Internet Only was allowed on the guest SSID i was connected to in my network)

I resolved the issue. I setup up two channels on my router (two different networks). 2.4GHz and 5GHz. I was connected to the 2.4GHz and tried switching to the 5GHz. That resolved the issue and now I am able to connect to my router!!!
This is becuase the 2.4GHz was a guest SSID (guest network) on my router. And my AT&T router on the guest SSID only allows "Internet Only" for network access. The main SSID allows for connections between devices within the same network
